# Facebook interstitial video ad crashes my app

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook, interstitial, video-ads

I am able to video Facebook interstitial image ads successfully but app crashes with video sound and blank screen while displaying video interstitial ad.

I mean sometimes I am unable to video the video but I can hear the sound and then app crashes immediately.

Comment: You may post stacktrace.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache from the app in app settings this trick might work.

Comment: Actually I have 2 apps the same code works for one app but not for another app.

Comment: I can also show my code if you want , so that you can let me know where I am doing wrong.